# ng-init with json file

Tags: angularjs, json

Can I use a json file in ng-init to get data of the json file ?

I have this example but I want to replace my object by the json file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app>
        <input type="text" ng-model="query"/>
        <div ng-init="users=['coucou', 'ca va']"> <!--to be replaced by data contains in a json file-->
            {{users}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="user in users">
                    {{user}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-init="getData()" ng-controller="listController">
    {{users}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        {{user}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "$http",
      function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getData = function() {
          $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.users = response.data;
          });
        }
      }
    ]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PLvXPHcqpGAyUiR3utPt?p=preview)**